# Microsoft Visual Studio GDB esp8266 application won't run alone

Tags: visual-studio, gdb, embedded, esp8266

I'm trying to setup a template Visual GDB Embedded Project in `Microsoft Visual Studio` with an example project.

> New->Project->Device(ESP8266)->Enable UART GDB Stub->Sample
>   Project(HTTP Server(RTOS SDK))

when I flash this thing through Uart Com-Port, the Server runs and I can access it. When I disconnect it and restart to run standalone(without uart), then It seems to hang and won't run at all.

I even tried to erase_flash in esptool.py and reflashed it with the resulting bin files in the

`debug output(without gdb_stub_init()`

being called)
SPI Flash is empty(0xFF in every Byte), so It should be an issue of the output files created.

the only thing I see now is a HotStop with the given name, when connected, the uart spits out: `$O6d617820636f6e6e656374696f6e210a#35`. The computer from where I connect says Connection could not be established, so it reacts only to the connection request.

UPDATE: a quick decode of the hex string to ascii gives: `"$Omax connection!#5"`, anyone an idea?

Answer (score -1):

Solved, the tweak was in New Embedded Project: keep gdb stub marked and remove gdb stub initial breakpoint
[image: Device Selection]
Also the wifi connection was bad, probably the wifi adapter of the laptop keeped requesting connection without success.